# HTML email issues in yahoo mail

Tags: html, css, email

Ok so I can't get my html email to have a max width in yahoo mail.

here is part of the html code im working with:

```
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" width="600" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0 auto !important;padding: 0;background-color: #fff;height: 100%;width: 100%; max-width: 600px !important;">
</body>
```

and the css:

```
body {
    /*@editable*/ background-color:#171717 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 600px !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Can anyone help with this.
Cheers

Comment: You have `width: 100% !important;` at the end of max-width, I am not sure but that does not seems to be right. Can you put it before your max-width statement in css?

Comment: @PM the order css declarations does not matter, updated anyway

Comment: It does matter, it works in the sequence you write it. See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570423/does-the-order-of-styles-matter)

Comment: yeah it does when multiple css selector declarations are used. so with `body {//any order in here it does not matter}` but with `.green { color: green; }
.red { color: red; }` it does matter the order.

Comment: p.s. thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a table for layout like below;

```html
<div style="max-width:600px;align-self:center;">
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
      <td style="padding:0;">
      <![endif]-->
        <table align="center" style="border-spacing:0;margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;background-color:#ff000a">
          <tr>
            <td>
            content
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      </td>
      </table>
      <![endif]-->
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work :( Came across it in my searching of google

Comment: Ok yeah my code was working originally, it was a problem with active campaign preview mode(which uses litmus too). p.s thanks for the help :)